# "The database instance is not set in the current thread" when using gremlin server to connect to Orientdb

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am using apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.2.5 to try to connect to orientdb-community-tp3-3.0.0m2.

I have installed the orientdb plugins for gremlin like this:
`bin/gremlin-server.sh -i com.orientechnologies orientdb-gremlin 3.0.0m2`

Then edited the gremlin-server.yaml configuration like this:

```
graphs: {
  graph: conf/orientdb-demodb.properties}
plugins:
  - tinkerpop.orientdb
```

I created orientdb-demodb.properties with following content:

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientGraph
orient-url=remote:localhost/demodb
orient-user=root
orient-pass=root
```

Then I'm using gremlinpython to try to connect to the gremlin-server like this:

```
from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import (
    DriverRemoteConnection)
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph


conn = DriverRemoteConnection(
    'ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 'g', pool_size=4)
g = Graph().traversal().withRemote(conn)
g.V().promise().result().toList()
```

When I run gremlin-server it starts and connects to orientdb:

```
[INFO] GremlinServer - 
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----

[INFO] GremlinServer - Configuring Gremlin Server from conf/gremlin-server-orientdb.yaml
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics ConsoleReporter configured with report interval=180000ms
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics CsvReporter configured with report interval=180000ms to fileName=/tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics JmxReporter configured with domain= and agentId=
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
[INFO] DefaultGraphManager - Graph [graph] was successfully configured via [conf/orientdb-demodb.properties].
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
[INFO] ScriptEngines - Loaded gremlin-groovy ScriptEngine
[INFO] GremlinExecutor - Initialized gremlin-groovy ScriptEngine with scripts/empty-sample.groovy
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing GremlinScriptEngines instances.
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized gremlin-groovy GremlinScriptEngine and registered metrics
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[orientgraph[remote:localhost/demodb], standard]
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the standard OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the control OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the session OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the traversal OpProcessor.
[INFO] TraversalOpProcessor - Initialized cache for TraversalOpProcessor with size 1000 and expiration time of 600000 ms
[INFO] GremlinServer - Executing start up LifeCycleHook
[INFO] Logger$info - Executed once at startup of Gremlin Server.
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo-lite with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo-stringd with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0
[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Gremlin Server configured with worker thread pool of 1, gremlin pool of 8 and boss thread pool of 1.
[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Channel started at port 8182.
```

When I run the python script it errors out and I get the following error in the gremlin-server console:

```
[WARN] TraversalOpProcessor - Exception processing a Traversal on iteration for request [9b736255-42da-4688-935e-a1e2f2f9cd93].
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: The database instance is not set in the current thread. Be sure to set it with: ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(db);
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.get(ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.java:51)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerAbstract.getDatabase(OIndexManagerAbstract.java:438)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerAbstract.getStorage(OIndexManagerAbstract.java:442)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerAbstract.getServerLocale(OIndexManagerAbstract.java:531)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerAbstract.getIndexOnProperty(OIndexManagerAbstract.java:537)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexManagerAbstract.getClassIndexes(OIndexManagerAbstract.java:347)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be some incompatibility between OrientDB and Gremlin Server given my reading of:

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Java-Multi-Threading.html

The problem is that OrientDB is not thread-safe. It requires an instance per thread. This approach conflicts a bit with TinkerPop's transaction model which assumes that a `Graph` instance can be used across threads.

I can't seem to think of a TinkerPop-sided workaround and after looking at the code for a little bit I'm not sure I see the problem. You may want to comment on this issue:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/issues/114

and reference this question to see if you can get some help from OrientDB devs.